# emacs shell-mode does not clear lines on carriage return

Tags: shell, emacs, carriage-return

Seems like I am running zsh session in emacs shell-mode. I have problem with some commands, e.g. `npm`, `yarn`, other node stuff. The line would not be clear and re-rendered, but all lines would be kept providing ugly long output that does not make much sense. I think it is something to do with carriage return character. Any knowledge how to fix that?

```
yarn remove jest
yarn remove v1.17.3
[1/2] Removing module jest...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
[] 0/522[] 56/522[] 123/522[] 181/522[] 255/522[] 327/522[] 388/522[] 451/522[] 520/522info fsevents@2.0.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.0.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[] 522/522[] 0/520[] 0/166[] 128/166[] 166/166[] 0/959[] 324/959[] 820/959[] 959/959
success Uninstalled packages.
Done in 3.83s.
```

```
yarn add jest
yarn add v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
⠈ resolve-cwd@^2.0.0⠁ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠂ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠄ resolve-from@^3.0.0⡀ resolve-from@^3.0.0⢀ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠠ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠐ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠈ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠁ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠂ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠄ resolve-from@^3.0.0⡀ resolve-from@^3.0.0⢀ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠠ resolve-from@^3.0.0⠐ yargs@^13.3.0⠈ yargs@^13.3.0⠁ yargs@^13.3.0⠂ yargs@^13.3.0⠄ yargs@^13.3.0⡀ yargs@^13.3.0⢀ yargs@^13.3.0⠠ yargs@^13.3.0⠐ yargs@^13.3.0⠈ yargs@^13.3.0⠁ yargs@^13.3.0⠂ yargs@^13.3.0⠄ ci-info@^2.0.0⡀ ci-info@^2.0.0⢀ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@^2.0.0⠠ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@^2.0.0⠐ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@^2.0.0⠈ strip-ansi@^5.0.0⠁ strip-ansi@^5.0.0⠂ strip-ansi@^5.0.0⠄ strip-ansi@^5.0.0⡀ strip-ansi@^5.0.0⢀ strip-ansi@^5.0.0⠠ pretty-format@^24.9.0⠐ source-map@^0.6.0⠈ sisteransi@^1.0.3⠁ sisteransi@^1.0.3⠂ realpath-native@^1.1.0⠄ realpath-native@^1.1.0⡀ realpath-native@^1.1.0⢀ realpath-native@^1.1.0⠠ realpath-native@^1.1.0⠐ realpath-native@^1.1.0⠈ realpath-native@^1.1.0⠁ @types/istanbul-lib-report@*⠂ @types/istanbul-lib-report@*⠄ @types/istanbul-lib-report@*⡀ @types/istanbul-lib-report@*⢀ yargs-parser@^13.1.1⠠ slash@^2.0.0⠐ slash@^2.0.0⠈ slash@^2.0.0⠁ string-length@^2.0.0⠂ string-length@^2.0.0⠄ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⡀ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⢀ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⠠ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⠐ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⠈ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⠁ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⠂ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⠄ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⡀ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⢀ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⠠ write-file-atomic@2.4.1⠐ throat@^4.0.0⠈ throat@^4.0.0⠁ throat@^4.0.0⠂ throat@^4.0.0⠄ throat@^4.0.0⡀ throat@^4.0.0⢀ fsevents@^1.2.7⠠ fsevents@^1.2.7⠐ fsevents@^1.2.7⠈ jest-snapshot@^24.9.0⠁ jest-snapshot@^24.9.0⠂ throat@^4.0.0⠄ throat@^4.0.0⡀ throat@^4.0.0⢀ throat@^4.0.0⠠ throat@^4.0.0⠐ p-reduce@^1.0.0⠈ p-reduce@^1.0.0⠁ string-length@^2.0.0⠂ string-length@^2.0.0⠄ string-length@^2.0.0⡀ yargs@^13.3.0⢀ yargs@^13.3.0⠠ semver@^6.2.0⠐ semver@^6.2.0⠈ semver@^6.2.0⠁ semver@^6.2.0⠂ semver@^6.2.0⠄ semver@^6.2.0⡀ semver@^6.2.0⢀ semver@^6.2.0⠠ semver@^6.2.0⠐ semver@^6.2.0⠈ semver@^6.2.0⠁ semver@^6.2.0⠂ source-map@^0.6.0⠄ object.getownpropertydescriptors@^2.0.3⡀ object.getownpropertydescriptors@^2.0.3⢀ object.getownpropertydescriptors@^2.0.3⠠ object.getownpropertydescriptors@^2.0.3⠐ react-is@^16.8.4⠈ react-is@^16.8.4⠁ react-is@^16.8.4⠂ react-is@^16.8.4⠄ react-is@^16.8.4⡀ jest-runtime@^24.9.0⢀ jest-runtime@^24.9.0⠠ jest-runtime@^24.9.0⠐ jest-runtime@^24.9.0⠈ jest-runtime@^24.9.0⠁ jest-runtime@^24.9.0⠂ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@*⠄ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@*⡀ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@*⢀ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@*⠠ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@*⠐ @types/istanbul-lib-coverage@*⠈ slash@^2.0.0⠁ jsdom@^11.5.1⠂ jsdom@^11.5.1⠄ jsdom@^11.5.1⡀ jsdom@^11.5.1⢀ jsdom@^11.5.1⠠ jsdom@^11.5.1⠐ throat@^4.0.0⠈ throat@^4.0.0⠁ throat@^4.0.0⠂ throat@^4.0.0⠄ jest-util@^24.9.0⡀ jest-util@^24.9.0⢀ jest-util@^24.9.0⠠ jest-util@^24.9.0⠐ jest-util@^24.9.0⠈ jest-util@^24.9.0⠁ jest-util@^24.9.0⠂ decamelize@^1.2.0⠄ decamelize@^1.2.0⡀ decamelize@^1.2.0⢀ decamelize@^1.2.0⠠ decamelize@^1.2.0⠐ jest-mock@^24.9.0⠈ supports-color@^6.1.0⠁ source-map@^0.6.1⠂ source-map@^0.6.1⠄ handlebars@^4.1.2⡀ handlebars@^4.1.2⢀ semver@^6.0.0⠠ semver@^6.0.0⠐ strip-ansi@^4.0.0⠈ strip-ansi@^4.0.0⠁ strip-ansi@^4.0.0⠂ which@^1.3.0⠄ supports-color@^6.1.0⡀ supports-color@^6.1.0⢀ supports-color@^6.1.0⠠ supports-color@^6.1.0⠐ test-exclude@^5.2.3⠈ test-exclude@^5.2.3⠁ test-exclude@^5.2.3⠂ signal-exit@^3.0.2⠄ signal-exit@^3.0.2⡀ signal-exit@^3.0.2⢀ signal-exit@^3.0.2⠠ strip-eof@^1.0.0⠐ bser@^2.0.0⠈ bser@^2.0.0⠁ bser@^2.0.0⠂ bser@^2.0.0⠄ bser@^2.0.0⡀ bser@^2.0.0⢀ bser@^2.0.0⠠ bser@^2.0.0⠐ bser@^2.0.0⠈ makeerror@1.0.x⠁ makeerror@1.0.x⠂ makeerror@1.0.x⠄ walker@~1.0.5⡀ walker@~1.0.5⢀ resolve@1.1.7⠠ resolve@1.1.7⠐ resolve@1.1.7⠈ resolve@1.1.7⠁ resolve@1.1.7⠂ detect-newline@^2.1.0⠄ detect-newline@^2.1.0⡀ pretty-format@^24.9.0⢀ pretty-format@^24.9.0⠠ pretty-format@^24.9.0⠐ pretty-format@^24.9.0⠈ pretty-format@^24.9.0⠁ pretty-format@^24.9.0⠂ pretty-format@^24.9.0⠄ pretty-format@^24.9.0
```

Comment: It's probably because `shell-mode` isn't a real terminal, and those tools are not detecting it as such.  What exactly are you running?

Comment: I have updated the question with examples.

Comment: My `yarn` behaves reasonably: https://pastebin.com/qNT5pF3J. It even has progress bars that don't show up in the final result.  You should use a newer `yarn` or a real terminal (like `term-mode`).

Comment: I am using the latest yarn. I do not think that there is anything to do with it. It is the `shell-mode`. So you are using `term-mode`, I am not. I like `shell-mode` more, and asking if there is a chance to improve `shell-mode` for that problem.

Comment: I prefer `term-mode`, but I'm definitely testing in `shell-mode`.  I have a running Emacs session that behaves as I described, but a fresh Emacs or `emacs -Q` behaves as you describe.  So I have some config somewhere that fixes it, but I'm not sure what, it's not obvious.  When I get time I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @jpkotta Any luck? Thank you.

Comment: So I messed around with this the other day.  I still have the same behavior where a long running Emacs works well and an fresh one behaves like yours.  I tried loading all files that were open in my old session in a fresh one, tried to load all the `features` in the old one into the new one too, and then started an `M-x shell`.  Same behavior.  I can't figure out what makes it work.  If you're interested, my config is at https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/dotemacs.  If I ever figure it out, I'll post an answer, but I'm not very hopeful.

Comment: Also, here's the `features` of the session that works well with `shell`: https://pastebin.com/uMuZZkA7.

Comment: @jpkotta Thank you. I wll have a look.